# WPF ResourceDictionary converter resource not found when startup project is a class library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, resourcedictionary

As a precursor to this long winded explanation, I have looked thought the existing posts and have not found what i was looking for, I have also googles the issue and also came up with nothing that solved my issue.

I'm a self thought C# WPF noob.
This is my first post, I hate asking for help as I hate wasting other people's time. But I find myself in a situation that I have not been able to solve. So if anyone can help shed some light on this I would be greatly appreciated.

I am working on an Autodesk Revit plugin. The Solution consists of three projects,

1. Addin Project, is a class library that implements Autodesk Reivt IExternalApplication interface that registers with Autodesk Revit.
2. Manager Project , is a WPF application that is called from the Addin class library project when the user clicks a button in the Revit User Interface.
3. Installer, (Not relevant to this issue)

My issue is related to the resources and MergedDictionaries in the WPF application.
I have style resources for the various controls that I need to style and also data and converter resources.

I add the resources to the App.axml resources section and also to the pages in the project. The reason for that is part of my issue.

When the user clicks to open the MainWindow from the Addin Project, the resources give issues in that they cant find "x" resource. The message looks like this:

**"Exception: Cannot find resource named 'FamTypeConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive."**

The converter is being used in a style for ListView CellTemplate which is in another recourse file.

The strange thing is that the resource file contains other resources that work just fine. But this one in particular is giving me issues. The resource is a converter that implements IValueConverter and currently does no conversion while I troubleshoot this issue, it just returns the value for the convert and convert back methods.

I have another converter in the same *.CS file called "FileSizeConverter" that simply converts an INT input into a formatted file size string. The Resources is in the same dictionary and points to it's converter in the same *.CS file, different class (obviously), witch one works perfectly.

I have tried using static and dynamic recourses, setting the build action of the resource xaml files to page, resource, Embedded Resource with no change in results.

I have tried adding the resource to the pages them-selves and tried relative and Pack url's. nothing seems to work. I also have to add the MergedDictionaries to the main window, pages and the app.xaml for the resources that do currently work, to work. if I don't add the resources to the pages I get the same error, cannot find "x" resource.

If I set the start up project to the WPF project, then there is no issue. All resources work. 
I think the issue is that the starting project does not load or cache the resources in the WPF project when the Window is in another project.

I'm 80% sure this is related to the fact that the WPF application extends "Application" and the class library does not! I presume the application class is where the resources are loaded but this is where my lack of knowledge kicks in.

I have no clue if I am on the right track or if I have missed something so obvious that I will want to kick myself when I realize what is wrong.

Sorry for the long winded explanation, and I hope that I have made myself clear and concise. If any clarity is required please feel free to request.

Thankyou in advance
Dereck Clements

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving any GridView styles to the page rather than a resource dictionary. I Think it was related to the converter being used in the resource dictionary that caused the issue to begin with. Having the GridView defined on the page solves the problem.